# How to get 2 or more records per unique column value in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

How to get 2 or more records per unique column value in ActiveRecord?

Given:

```
Name     | School
Jonathan | Sunshine College 
Dylan    | Sunshine College
Matt     | Sunshine College
Joseph   | Sunshine College
Stephen  | Greenville School
Phil     | Greenville School
Warren   | Greenville School  
JohnPaul | Greenville School
```

then if I wanted to output ***2 records*** per school, it will look like this:

```
Name     | School
Jonathan | Sunshine College 
Dylan    | Sunshine College
Stephen  | Greenville School
Phil     | Greenville School
```

If I wanted ***3 records*** per school then it'll look like this:

```
Name     | School
Jonathan | Sunshine College 
Dylan    | Sunshine College
Matt     | Sunshine College
Stephen  | Greenville School
Phil     | Greenville School
Warren   | Greenville School
```

Comment: What DBMS ("database") are you using?

Comment: do you want 'Matt' and 'Warren' to appear in the output table? If you're just trying to eliminate duplicate name/school pairs, then Matt and Warren should be there. Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: do you want any 2 records or you need to apply some sorting?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I'm using Postgres

Comment: @LesNightingill could be, it really depends on the input, if I input 1 per school, then it should only show only jonathan and stephen. If it's 3 per school then get jonathan, dylan and matt for sunshine, then stephen, phil and warren for greenville

Comment: @AbdulRehman no need to sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can partition the data of the table by the column value you need. After that you can use a condition to tell how many records per partition you want:

```
Student
  .from(
    Student.select('*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY school) AS rownum')
  )
  .select('*')
  .where('rownum < 2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a way without using sql.

```
Student.group(:school)
   .each{|student| Student.where(school: student.school)
   .first(2)
   .each{|result| puts "#{result.name.ljust(20, ' ')}| #{result.school}"}}

# Phil                | Greenville School
# Warren              | Greenville School
# Jonathan            | Sunshine College
# Dylan               | Sunshine College
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `uniq` when you have transformed the collections of models in to a list of attributes which can be compared for equality:

```
MyModel.all.pluck(:first_name, :last_name).uniq
```

Comment: I could use that but where can I put an "N" variable to get N unique records per school.

So if N input is 2 then I should get 2 records per school like the example above

Comment: You have changed the question since I answered.

Comment: Yes, I did, uniq still apply, but the output remains the same. I also added another result set just to be more clear.